# Roll over link == change class. Roll out of div == change class back. Not working. Help

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation

That's my issue in its simplest terms.  Let me try to clear it up.

I have a `div`, in this case called `"testdiv"`, which has a class name of `"menulink"` attached to it.  There is a link inside of the `div`.  When I roll over the link, I want the `div` class to change to `"menulinkHover"`.  When I roll *out* of the `div`, however, I want the class to revert back to `"menulink"`.  To do this, I am using `getElementByID`.  Rolling over the link works perfectly, but as soon as I roll out of the `link`, *not the `div`*, the class reverts back.

Here is a fiddle with what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/nathanbunn/KJMsf/

I'm working on this with jQuery, using `.removeClass` and `.addClass` in the same manner, but I fear I will get the same issue.  I've missed something, I know I've missed something, but what is it?  For an idea of what I'm looking for, have a look on the [Harvey Nichols](http://www.harveynichols.com/) homepage.  I know they use Prototype for their framework of choice.

Can this be done with the script I have?  Am I right and I have indeed missed something?  Can it work better in jQuery?  Can it be done in pure CSS, even?  Please help.  I'm at a complete loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set it up to use JQuery as I always find it better than pure javascript. I got it to work by setting the link to have a mouseenter that adds a class to the div and then the div itself has a mouseleave that removes the class. It now works fine for me. Here's the link:
http://jsfiddle.net/KJMsf/6/

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted (minus the pizazz that Caro Calo gave, which is one of the things that made me go "oooooooooh").  Here was me residing myself to the possibility that I (personally) was limited to using CSS to get my desired, thank you, both of you, for proving me wrong :)

Comment: If you want a bit of pizazz you can use JQuery UI's animate function to do something like the fade in event: http://jsfiddle.net/KJMsf/7/. JQuery UI also has toggleClass fucniton but it doesn't seem to work well with quick hovers.

Answer (score 3):

Combine CSS with jquery mouse event and fadein/out, and you should get what you want. An example is : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/carocalo/gQeWD/2/)

Comment: Ooooooooh, even better ... I thought I had found a pure CSS solution just now, but yours looks considerably better with the fade in / out ...